# Only one button is getting displayed in java awt

Tags: java, button, awt, frame, layout-manager

I am trying to create a display with multiple buttons on it. However, only one button is being displayed. Why is this happening? Is it something with the layout manager? Where did I go wrong?

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
class ButtonDemo extends Frame 
{
    Button[] b;Frame frame;
    ButtonDemo()
    {
        int i=0;
        b=new Button[12];
        frame=new Frame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        for (i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            b[i] = new Button("Hello"+i);frame.add(b[i]);
        }
        frame.add(new Button("Hello"));
        frame.add(new Button("polo"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ButtonDemo bd = new ButtonDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want all the components to appear vertically or horizontally, I would suggest using a `BoxLayout`, else just use a `FlowLayout`. Although, it is kind of unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour from `BorderLayout`.

`BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to reside in each of it's 5 available positions.

You are adding two buttons to the same position so only the last one will be displayed.

Try...

- Adding one button to the `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH` positions
- Using a different layout manager

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details...

Answer (score 1):

Like `MadProgrammer` said, it's because of the `BorderLayout`
Just declare another layout and it should work:

```
import java.awt.*;
class ButtonDemo extends Frame 
{
    Button[] b;Frame frame;
    ButtonDemo()
    {
        int i=0;
        b=new Button[12];
        frame=new Frame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        for (i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            b[i] = new Button("Hello"+i);frame.add(b[i]);
        }
        frame.add(new Button("Hello"));
        frame.add(new Button("polo"));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ButtonDemo bd = new ButtonDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is recommended not to add components to frame but to it's **Container**. Easiest way is to add JPanel to the frame's Container and then any subsequent components to this JPanel.

For example

```
    JFrame customFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel customPanel = new JPanel();
    customPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    customFrame.getContentPane().add(customPanel);
    //add your buttons to customPanel
```

Secondly you have made a custom class ButtonDemo which extends Frame then **why are you again creating a frame in it?** In your case you can directly say

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // equivalent to this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 add(new Button("polo"));
```

instead of creating a separate frame and adding components/layout to it.

You are setting the layout of your frame as BorderLayout but not using any of it's features.

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

If you want your button to be on your desires position(say NORTH) you have to specify so

```
frame.add(new Button("Hello"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Again if you want multiple buttons in NORTH position then use a Panel with **BoxLayout**(Horizontal or vertical whatever is your requirement) and then add your buttons to it.